# Node Js Function Declaration and Expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started to learn Node Js then I got the following code in the tutorial

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const questions = [
  "What is your name? ",
  "Where do you live? ",
  "What are you going to do with node js? "
];

const collectAnswers = (questions, done) => {
  const answers = [];
  const [firstQuestion] = questions;

  const questionAnswered = answer => {
    answers.push(answer);
    if (answers.length < questions.length) {
      rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered);
    } else {
      done(answers);
    }
  };

  rl.question(firstQuestion, questionAnswered);
};

collectAnswers(questions, answers => {
  console.log("Thank you for your answers. ");
  console.log(answers);
  process.exit();
});
```

The code has the following result

```
What is your name? a
Where do you live? b
What are you going to do with node js? c
Thank you for your answers.
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

As far as I understand that the variable collectAnswer somehow inject the function declared below to the second parameter (**done**). Can someone explain what is actually happening behind the scene? How can the function declared below injected to the variable with the same name with it? Any term this pattern actually called?

Comment: `done` is one of its parameters. The caller provides a function as the argument.

Comment: it is called`callback` function, since `Node.js` is `async` in nature

Comment: @AbishekKumar This has nothing to do with asynchrony. It's like the callback to `forEach()`.

Comment: in the last part of the question, he is asking about what is it called, and we use callback, because of Node.js async nature. Where you need to run a specific code after the function completes.

Comment: _"How can the function declared below injected to the variable **with the same name with it**?"_ - What name are you talking about?

Comment: @AbishekKumar - While callbacks are often used in asynchronous programming, they aren't *specific* to asynchronous programming. Many callbacks are synchronous, not asynchronous (for example, the callbacks used by `map` and `filter` on arrays or, as Barmar pointed out, `forEach`).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just confuse myself because many arrow function and same variable name. I think `collectAnswers(questions, answers =>{})` at the bottom is defining a new function, but it actually just calling the function defined before. T.J. Crowder has explain it pretty clear

Comment: @T.J.Crowder try to run db call or API call inside forEach, it won't run synchronously, for that we used `async` npm module or `for in` or `for of`

Comment: @AbishekKumar - Which is completely irrelevant. The callback that `forEach` makes is synchronous. It's just that (in your example) it's starting an asynchronous task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects in JavaScript, unlike some other languages, so you can pass them into functions as arguments and the functions can receive them as parameters. This is done a lot so that the function you're calling can "call back" to your code (the function you're passing in). A function used this way is often called a "callback." A function like `collectAnswers` that accepts a function it's going to call this way is often described as a function that "accepts a callback."

In that code, there's a function called `collectAnswers` and it accepts two parameters, `questions` and `done`:

```
const collectAnswers = (questions, done) => {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^−−^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− parameters
    // ...
};
```

At the end, the code *calls* `collectAnswers`, passing in an array of questions and new function created inline as the second argument (I've put the two arguments on separate lines for clarity):

```
collectAnswers(
    questions,                                          // 1st argument

    answers => {                                        //
        console.log("Thank you for your answers. ");    //
        console.log(answers);                           // 2nd argument
        process.exit();                                 //
    }                                                   //
);
```

That does the same thing as this, except for the `callback` constant:

```
const callback = answers => {
    console.log("Thank you for your answers. ");
    console.log(answers);
    process.exit();
};
collectAnswers(questions, callback);
```